# При написании классов в models.py в классе Order возникает ошибка "Instance of 'Order' has no 'id' member"

Tags: python, django

При написании моделей в models.py в классе Order возникает ошибка "Instance of 'Order' has no 'id' member".

Компилятор выдает ошибку и подсвечивает этот блок кода: `def __str__(self): return str(self.id)`

Как это исправить?

Спасибо

файл [models.py](https://github.com/mikezigberman/models/blob/main/models.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно так:

```
def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'
```